# Learning Swift, Value of optional type not unwrapped when creating an object

Tags: swift

I'm learning Swift right now, and in the course we have a lesson to make a simple app. Now I'm having problems with some text fields programming that it's not working properly.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var refeicaoField: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet weak var felicidadeField: UITextField?


    @IBAction func addRefeicao(sender: UIButton) {

        if refeicaoField == nil || felicidadeField == nil {
            return
        }

        let nomeRefeicao = refeicaoField!.text
        let valorFelicidade = felicidadeField!.text
        let valorFelicidadeInt = Int(valorFelicidade!)

        let novaRefeicao = Meal(nomeAlimento: nomeRefeicao, alegriaEmComer: valorFelicidadeInt)
    }


}
```

The problem starts here:

```
    let novaRefeicao = Meal(nomeAlimento: nomeRefeicao, alegriaEmComer: valorFelicidadeInt)
```

Where it says: value of optional 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' and also value of optional 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'

I'm little confused, because in the lesson example they have done like this:

```
    let novaRefeicao = Meal(nomeAlimento: nomeRefeicao, alegriaEmComer: valorFelicidadeInt!)
```

And worked, but for me no. And if I try to put '!' at the two variables, I have an exclamation warning prompting no use for let novaRefeicao.

What's wrong?

**EDIT:**

Done some changes using all the tips found here, now my code is like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var refeicaoField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var felicidadeField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func addRefeicao(sender: UIButton) {

        if refeicaoField == nil || felicidadeField == nil {
            return
        }

        let nomeRefeicao = refeicaoField!.text
        let valorFelicidade = felicidadeField!.text

        if nomeRefeicao == nil {
            return
        }

        if let valorFelicidadeInt = Int(valorFelicidade!) {
            let novaRefeicao = Meal(nomeAlimento: nomeRefeicao, alegriaEmComer: valorFelicidadeInt)
        } else {
            return
        }
    }


}
```

Now I receive the error on unwrapped again, but now with the "nomeRefeicao" instead. Tried to put the '!' in it, but then it shows that let novaRefeicao is immutable value.

Comment: If the `IBOutlet`s are supposed to be connected in Interface Builder, it's pretty meaningless to declare them as optionals (`?`).  If your course suggests that, go for a better course. The way recommended by Apple is to  declare them as implicit unwrapped optional(`!`) because they are safely non-nil when connected. The benefit is to get rid of all exclamation marks to unwrap them in the code and of course the checking for `nil` each time the method is called is not needed, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `text` property of `UITextField` and the result of the `Int(string:String)` initializer return an optional value.

So you have to unwrap **both** in case the method expects non optional parameters.

```
let novaRefeicao = Meal(nomeAlimento: nomeRefeicao!, alegriaEmComer: valorFelicidadeInt!)
```

The most compact syntax is

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var refeicaoField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var felicidadeField: UITextField!


  @IBAction func addRefeicao(sender: UIButton) {

    if let nomeRefeicao = refeicaoField.text, valorFelicidade = felicidadeField.text, valorFelicidadeInt = Int(valorFelicidade) {
      let novaRefeicao = Meal(nomeAlimento: nomeRefeicao, alegriaEmComer: valorFelicidadeInt)
      // do something with novaRefeicao
    }
  }
}
```

The `Meal` initializer is only called if

- `refeicaoField.text` is not `nil`
- `felicidadeField.text` is not `nil` and can be converted to `Int`

There is no need to check the `UITextField` instances for `nil`.
If you get a runtime error, one of the fields is not connected in IB.

The message `Initialization of immutable value ...` is a warning, because the created `Meal` instance assigned to `novaRefeicao` is never used. That's why I added the comment line *do something …*

Comment: Hey! If I try to do that, I have an error of immutable variable in let novaRefeicao.

Comment: If you need to use `novaRefeicao` as a variable rather than a constant, replace `let` with `var`

Comment: Sorry, I use it as a let, but when I try to use '!' in nomeRefeicao, I receive a "Initialization of immutable value". if let valorFelicidadeInt = Int(valorFelicidade!) {
            let novaRefeicao = Meal(nomeAlimento: nomeRefeicao!, alegriaEmComer: valorFelicidadeInt)

Comment: First of all you have also to unwrap the created `Int` - `Int(valorFelicidade!)!` but the cause of the error could be also in the `Meal` class.

Answer (score 3):

You should understand that the Swift language has changed a **lot** over the past year and that exclamation point has moved quite a bit over time. If your examples are from even mid-2015, you're looking at out-dated syntax.

Having a value with `?` means that this item may contain a value... or it may not.

Having a value with `!` means that you are forcibly unwrapping an object which can be rather dangerous, use it sparingly and only when you know for certain that it will not cause a crash.

If you have an optional value, you can safely unwrap it like this:

```
guard let unwrapped = wrapped else {
    return
}
```

or

```
if let unwrapped = wrapped {
    print(unwrapped)
}
```

A little more info, if you have an initialized optional value, what you've really got is this:

```
enum Optional<A> {
    case None
    case Some(A)
}
```

This is why you cannot use your value without unwrapping it... it's 'wrapped' in an optional enum that either has a value or doesn't.

**Your code with a little safeguard added:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var refeicaoField: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet weak var felicidadeField: UITextField?


    @IBAction func addRefeicao(sender: UIButton) {

        guard let refeicaoField = refeicaoField!.text else {
            return
        }

        guard let felicidadeField = felicidadeField!.text else {
            return
        }

        let nomeRefeicao = refeicaoField ?? "error" // added protection
        let valorFelicidade = felicidadeField ?? "error"  // added protection
        let valorFelicidadeInt = Int(valorFelicidade) ?? 0 // defaults to '0' in case of issue
    }
}
```

Comment: why not simply 0 as 'default' value? :-)

Comment: hm ... i don't understand, disregard please, i am going to think about you note.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
let valorFelicidadeInt = Int(valorFelicidade!)
```

converts a `String` value into an `Int`.  What should your code do if the string cannot be converted to an integer?  You need to address that explicitly.

In Swift, the conversion has a type of `Optional` - either the conversion worked or it did not.  You thus have two cases to cover.  The following is a possible approach:

```
if let valorFelicidadeInt = Int(valorFelicidade!) {
  let novaRefeicao = Meal(nomeAlimento: nomeRefeicao, alegriaEmComer: valorFelicidadeInt)
  // continue using `Meal`
}
else {
  // User error; text not an int
}
```

The `if let` will succeed if `Int(...)` returns a non-nil optional; you'll then build the `Meal`.

The same approach to unwrapping by handling the two options applies to other parts of your code.

Comment: Sorry for late to reply. I was busy. Done that! But, I continue to receive an error now with the nomeRefeicao element inside your if. Tried to put a '!' there, but then variable says it immutable variable.

Comment: "Initialization of immutable value"*

Comment: That is what I meant by 'the same approach to unwrapping' - you need to apply the solution I described to a couple of your variables.  Focus on the values that are `Optional` - the `.text` function returns an `Optional`, I believe.  What happens if there is no text?  Maybe use `(refeicaoField!.text ?? "")`